# Beginner: Converting Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

First post here, please go easy on me. Found several threads with similar issues, none of those applied directly or if one did, the execution was far enough over my head.

If i have code `p=['1','2','3','4']` that stores digits as characters in `p`, how do i create a list `q` that can equal `[1,2,3,4]`?
I've been trying all sorts of things, mostly arriving at my q being out of scope or any function i try to convert `Char -> Int` lacking accompanying binding.
I seem to find indication everywhere that there is such a thing as `digitToInt`, where `digitToInt '1'` should yield an output of `1` but i apparently lack bindings, even with the exact input from this page:
http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputchar/digitToInt_f.html

At this point reading more things i am just becoming more confused. Please help with either a viable solution that might show me where i'm messing up or with an explanation why this `digitToInt :: Char -> Int` seems to not work for me in the slightest.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to import `Data.Char` to have access to the `digitToInt` function. You can then `map` the function to the list, with `map digitToInt p`. Also note that `['1', '2', '3', '4']` is equivalent to `"1234"`.

Comment: @domi When you are looking for a function or a function matching a known signature, use [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) to look around all of Hackage or [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) for standard librairies.

Comment: @gxtaillon I'm stuck at a much simpler level. Before i start looking for more functions, i should at least get the really basic ones to work for me, and it seems that every single line that i write something like x::... i get back Not in scope 'x'.
I'm following youtube tutorials and getting that on the same stuff that i see working for others. Not sure if using Eclipse could cause that, but it seems very strange to me...

Comment: @domi Eclipse? Last time I checked the plugins were far from being useful, at all. For all purposes, I'd stick to a text editor and `ghci` for simple applications and `cabal` for bigger ones. Have you used `ghci` yet?

Comment: No, I wanted to get used to working in an environment that gives me a notepad area for code and also a panel for console commands, so i can play around in console and then add to source when it works. I guess i got used to MatLab and am too attached to quick running now. =<
I'll heed your advice and try `ghci` now, but if you can think of a decent split-screen environment please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`digitToInt` is something that already exists. It used to live in the `Char` module but now it lives in `Data.Char`, so we have to `import Data.Char` to use it.

```
Prelude> import Data.Char
Prelude Data.Char> digitToInt '1'
1
```

You can use `digitToInt` on every element of a list with `map digitToInt`. `map :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]` applies a function `(a->b)` to each element of a list of `a`s, `[a]` to get a list of `b`s, `[b]`.

```
Prelude Data.Char> map digitToInt ['1', '2', '3', '4']
[1,2,3,4]
```

#### Lacks an accompanying binding

You don't need to define `digitToInt` or other imports by writing it's type signature `digitToInt :: Char -> Int`. A signature written without a binding like that

```
alwaysSeven :: Char -> Int
```

will give the following error.

```
The type signature for `alwaysSeven' lacks an accompanying binding
```

You only provide a type signature when it comes right before a declaration.

```
alwaysSeven :: Char -> Int
alwaysSeven x = 7
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of importing modules.

Answer (score 0):

Without importing anything you can also use a very simply trick, and push (`(:[])`) the character in an empty list (making a singleton list) before `read`ing the value:

```
map (read . (:[])) "1234"
```

This will need the context of the type of the list to be deducible, but it will work for any type you want without modifications. Otherwise you'll need to specify the type yourself:

```
(map (read . (:[])) "1234") :: [Int]
-- [1,2,3,4]
(map (read . (:[])) "1234") :: [Double]
-- [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
```